# Is it sensible to use a public and private key encryption between a client server model?

Tags: java, security, rsa

My plan to make my server harder to emulate goes as follows;

The client creates a random string, String random;

This string is then encrypted and sent to the server. The server then decrypts it and sends it back, if the one sent back is the same as random, then they are connected to the right server (and not a fake one with a diff private key).

How can I make it so that each client has the public key and the server holds the private key? Not a clue.

EDIT -

Because I do not want the clients to have to have extra files for  the public key, can I allow them to download the public key on runtime? If I hold it on the server and like serialize it? How?

Comment: Why roll your own? Java has SSL support in the standard library.

Comment: Are you actually looking for a self-signed certificate on the server?

Comment: SSL support? Let me look into thhat.

Comment: Just SSL/TLS + server certificate in truststore

Comment: @pedrofb how? Any exampes?

Comment: Do not download the public key/certificate from server. It breaks trust, because if an attacker do a ManInTheMiddle attack it could provide a different certificate and you have no way to know it. The certificate must be provided to clients using a different channel: offline, embedded in app, published in your website, etc.

Comment: SSL/TLS is a standard protocol implemented in all servers. 1) Buy/generate your own certificate and install in your server 2)provide the public certificate to your clients 3) connect to your server using a TLS secure channel (https) using a trust store that must contain the certificate. TLS do the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it sensible to use a public and private key encryption between a
>   client server model?

In a word? No.  At least not the way you describe it.

You could get this to work as described, but you will have created security theater rather than effective security.

- If you use public/private key pairs that are *not* bound to certificates, you have a key exchange problem.  As noted in the comments, if the app just downloads the key from the server to which it connects, and that key is not in a certificate, there's no way to tell it's authentic to the intended server.
- If you use public-/private keys bound to certificates it solves your key exchange problem since you can download the cert from the target server and inspect the Subject Distinguished Name and Issuer Distinguished Name to discover whether the public key you have is authentic.  But once you have gone to the trouble of deploying certificates, just use TLS.  It's there, it's reliable, and most importantly it's been thoroughly hammered at and known bugs fixed so its as trustworthy as we have available.  Your home-grown protocol is not.
- What you are describing can be achieved with other standard protocols such as Challenge-Handshake Authentication Protocol (CHAP).  If TLS doesn't meet your requirement, use a standard protocol.  Even an old deprecated one would be better than writing your own because, like TLS, it's been hammered on extensively in the real world.
- Assuming that you did implement the protocol proposed, then what?  Authenticate then communicate in plaintext?  Why expend more effort than implementing TLS, to deploy something far less secure than TLS, that doesn't even provide privacy or integrity of transmitted data?

> Because I do not want the clients to have to have extra files for the
>   public key, can I allow them to download the public key on runtime? If
>   I hold it on the server and like serialize it? How?

If you use CA signed certificates (from an internal or external CA) you can dynamically fetch the certificates from the target server.  The only thing you need to store is the signer chain in your Trust Store and the acceptable values for Subject Distinguished Name and Issuer Distinguished Name.  The remote cert won't validate if the signer certs are not in the Trust Store so a man in the middle can't just swap out any cert with the right distinguished names.  Once it validates to your Trust Store, your inspection of the distinguished names determines if you have the right cert and server.

Finally, the question doesn't mention revocation at all.  If you use CA-signed certs from a commercial CA or from an internal CA that is at least somewhat robust, you can check at run time against a Certificate Revocation List or use Online Certificate Status Protocol.  Again, these are *built into* the TLS protocol as implemented in any JSSE standard provider.